# application bar icon button over rides original designer windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, facebook-share

im using following code for showing application bar in wp app

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Minimized" BackgroundColor="#FF3E5F99">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/fb.png" Text="Facebook"  Click="btnFB_onClick" IsEnabled="True"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

it shows correct icon button in designer but the problem is, if i run the app it shows X as icon button instead of F Facebook icon button

Comment: Is the File's Build Action set to Content?

Comment: im not getting the fb.png file in Assets folder even after refresh

Comment: That didn't make any sense, clarify.

Comment: @Chubosaurus Software i ve copied fb.png into Assets folder thru file explorer. after refreshing solutions explorer fb.png is not visible.  anything is wrong in my side?

Comment: Yeah, you can't do it that way.  Right click on the Assets -> Add Existing Item

Comment: Yes its set to content. now im getting fb icon at run time.

Comment: Sweet :), I posted the solution underneath.  Please mark it as a the solution when you have the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marek problem is not solved even after i made your suggestions though.

i changed to generic share icon it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `UriKind` to `Relative`/`RelativeOrAbsolute` I suggest to use following code on `Page Load` event

```
ApplicationBar appBar = new ApplicationBar();
appBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
appBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;
appBar.IsVisible = true;
appBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(120, 0,229,249)

ApplicationBarIconButton button = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
button.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/fb.png", UriKind.Relative);
button.Text = "Facebook";
button.Click += btnFB_onClick(null, null);
button.IsEnabled = true;
appBar.Add(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it shows up in Designer View and not runtime it is usually because it is deployed incorrectly.

Check to see if the file in the `Assets Folder` has a Build Action of `Content` like below (just click on the file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer)

[image]

---

If the file is not in the Assets Folder then Right click on the Assets Folder -> Add Existing Item